# Is there any way to encrypt "appsettings.json" in .net core web application using "ASPNET_REGIIS"

Tags: asp.net-core, encryption, configuration

Is there any way to encrypt "appsettings.json" in the .net core web application using "ASPNET_REGIIS"

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but I wanted to comment because I understand you shouldn't put any sensitive information in appsettings.json at all.

There is a system called User Secrets that allows you to store sensitive information. Documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows

I hope that's some help.

Comment: Where do you plan on deploying this application?

Comment: @GlennSills I need to deploy my application to an internal production server, where I should not expose the service account details in plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is 'no there in no way to encrypt you appsettings.json using ASPNET_REGIIS. One solution you might consider is storing secrets in Azure Key Vault. The cost of using this one service is minimal ($0.03 for 10,000 transactions) and it has a Microsoft.Extension.Configuration provider that makes it easy to use. [Azure Key Vault Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

The alternative is rolling your own package that uses the DataProtection API which is not all that hard to code, but painful to manage.

Also, it is important to note that User Secrets are great, but they are just for developers, you should **not** attempt to use them in production settings. The data in User Secrets is not encrypted, instead they are protected under the account of the user in question. It is possible to make this work on a server but you shouldn't.